# How to extend vuejs Composition API script?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, extend, code-reuse, vue-composition-api

I have multiple components(textField, radioField,numberField ,...) which share the logic part, for example:

```
//baseInputField.ts
import {createComponent} from "@vue/composition-api";
import {
  useInputFieldComposition,
  inputFieldProps
} from "@/mixins/Helpers/FormGeneratorInputFieldHelper/inputField.composition";
import {ComponentPropsOptions} from "@vue/composition-api/dist/component/componentProps";

export default createComponent({
  props: inputFieldProps as ComponentPropsOptions,
  setup(props, context) {
    const {inputField, updateValue} = useInputFieldComposition(props, context);
    return {
      inputField, updateValue
    }
  }
});
```

currently i use src  in script tag for each components which only needs the base compoenent like below, and it works(**but seems like sharing an object not a new one, that makes my select Options to be like a textField, which i dont want it**):

```
//numberField.vue
<script lang="ts" src="../scripts/inputFieldScriptTag.ts">
</script>
```

and for those like radioField.vue which has some more code(here just a "**colorStateCheck**" as you can see in the below code) than baseInputField.ts, i couldnt extend it properly and use it.

```
//radioField.vue
  import {createComponent} from "@vue/composition-api";
  import {
    useInputFieldComposition,
    inputFieldProps
  } from "@/mixins/Helpers/FormGeneratorInputFieldHelper/inputField.composition";
  import {ComponentPropsOptions} from "@vue/composition-api/dist/component/componentProps";
  import {FormGeneratorInputFieldsLabelValuePairs} from "@/types";

  export default createComponent({
    name: "RadioField",
    props: inputFieldProps as ComponentPropsOptions,
    setup(props, context) {
      const {inputField, updateValue} = useInputFieldComposition(props, context);
      const colorStateCheck = (item: FormGeneratorInputFieldsLabelValuePairs) => {
        if (inputField.inputValue === item.value) {
          if (item.value === false) {
            return 'color:red';
          } else {
            return 'color:#84CE95';
          }
        }
        return ''
      };
      return {
        inputField, updateValue, colorStateCheck
      }

    }
  });
```

is there any proper way to do this?

.....

(if you want to go this path from option api to composition api and fix you problems , you can follow this ask [odd problems in Convert Vuejs Typescript Options to Composition Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947146/odd-problems-in-convert-vuejs-typescript-options-to-composition-api/59952312#59952312) ,which i made it to this step here in this ask)

Comment: _"i couldnt extend it properly"_ … what is not properly extended?

Comment: Maybe [the documentation (section "Logic Extraction and Reuse")](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/#logic-extraction-and-reuse) can help.

Comment: thank you @Paleo , I did read the article, but it is a little bit diffrent from what it is being said in the doc. 
if you want to do the same thing which i told in the question, how would you do that?